# v4 OData: The feed's metadata document appears to be invalid

Tags: odata

I'm creating an OData service but I'm unable to load the data in Excel and Power BI, I'm getting the invalid metadata error. My sample service is at http://ltserver2.cloudapp.net/pts4rest/api/xlreport.demo/xlreport/query/test

I can't see anything wrong with the metadata or the data.  Are there any OData validator/tester available?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

pt

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  I was missing the content-type : odata.metadata=minimal.  It's now working.

Comment: how did you find that this header was missing ? isn't application/xml enough ? did you have some validators ?